# Data structure for a CSV file using OpenAI and LangChains CSVLoader

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

OK this maybe a stupid question but I can't find an answer anywhere.  I am trying to load a csv file into an openAI application that will use that US Cancer Related data.  I am trying to determine the "best" data structure for doing queries.  What I mean is:

Is it better to have each item in a separate row or does adding a column work the same way.  Such as

```
| State | County     | Cancer  | Rate |
|-------|------------|---------|------|
|SC     | Charleston | Bladder | 3.9  |
|SC     | Dorchester | Bladder | 4.4  |
|SC     | Pickens    | Bladder | 3.4  |
|SC     | Charleston | Colon   | 1.9  |
|SC     | Dorchester | Colon   | 8.5  |
|SC     | Pickens    | Colon   | 3.4  |
```

or

```
| State | County     | Bladder_Rate | Colon_Rate | 
|-------|------------|--------------|------------|
|SC     | Charleston | 3.9          | 1.9        |
|SC     | Dorchester | 4.4          | 8.5        |
|SC     | Pickens    | 3.4          | 3.4        |
```

The questions will only apply to the data that is on the csv file.  Is there a public resource that has determine the accuracy of the responses based upon the data structure and the models selected.  This will pretty much use static data so I'm willing to try and find the most accurate structure.  However; that being said if a Researcher asks a question and the answer is a total hallucination then the app will never be used again.  This will house all of the data in the United States, published by the governmental resources for every county in every state for every cancer type that they follow.  But the data does not change very often.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a good question. And if you don't want to read more, the short answer is: **Test and optimize your prompt**. I've seen this produce great results based on my use cases, so I believe it will also apply to you.

---

Here are the details:

There are a couple of key points that have been consistently providing accurate responses in my app. So, if I were you, I'd attempt to try both of the points below:

1. Use a Well Defined Prompt
2. Implement and Test for Accuracy

### Use a Well Defined Prompt

What is a well-defined prompt? It's basically the key instructions and context you give a Large Language Model such as GPT-4 to process subsequent user queries.

Having a well-defined, clear, and detailed prompt is a great way to ensure that the output (or answer) will be aligned with your expectations.

For your specific use case, I would clearly instruct the model to process the data based on the provided structure. Meaning, that I will embed the table structure within the initial prompt and then also include an explanation of what each column and row contains and means. Then, given this information, I'd ask the LLM to provide an answer as required.

Here's an example of how to set up your `PromptTemplate` using LangChain:

```py
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

prompt_template = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    "Tell me a {adjective} joke about {content}."
)
prompt_template.format(adjective="funny", content="chickens")
```

You can check [this post](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/prompt_templates/) for more information about prompts.

*(Note: A solid prompt will greatly benefit you if you ever decide to change the LLM powering your app as it provides any model with the problem, instructions, and expected output.)*

### Implement and Test for Accuracy

A follow-up task is to embed **both** data structures from your CSV file and test the output of the model for each. So create two prompts, each including a different structure, and see which one produces a better answer.

You can then tweak your prompt by implementing necessary changes with each iteration until you have the desired output.

Test this out and let me know which one you end up choosing and why!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the questions, the prompt, and the (OpenAI) model you are using. Currently, Language Models (LLMs) struggle with math calculations. So, if your questions involve calculations (perhaps just additions or mean values), I would prefer to insert a table into the prompt that explicitly shows the relevant final values.

As mentioned in the previous comment, design your prompt by specifying all instructions that help prevent the LLM from making up information.